# Manejo de archivos en C++

Tags: c++, archivo

Tengo una serie de objetos de clase *Mutante*, que tengo que escribir en formato **CSV** en un archivo externo. En un principio, he intentado usar solo el nombre del archivo para crearlo y usarlo:

```
void almacenaMutantesCSV(Mutante* v[], int tamv, std::string nombreArchivo) {
    std::fstream archivo;
    archivo.open(nombreArchivo);
    if (archivo.good()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tamv; i++) {
            archivo << v[i]->toCSV() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Pero no tengo ni idea de si ese archivo se está creando correctamente, no se está creado, o dónde está. No lo encuentro en ninguna carpeta del proyecto. Por tanto, he decidido que es mejor crearlo en una ruta específica, por ejemplo (la carpeta de proyecto) `E:\Universidad\Programacion Orientada a Objetos\Practicas\Ejercicios hechos\Practica 7\P_7_Material\nombreArchivo`, pero el compilador se vuelve directamente loco:

```
main.cpp:51:20: error: stray '\' in program //De estos muchisimos
main.cpp:51:19: error: found ':' in nested-name-specifier, expected '::'
main.cpp:51:18: error: 'E' has not been declared
```

Probando y Googleando he puesto dos barras (**\**),  la **e** minúscula... pero NADA da resultados.

Os dejo el código entero del **Main**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "EquipoMutante.h"

using namespace std;

/***@brief Visualiza la información completa de un mutante*/
void visualiza(Mutante& m) {
    std::cout << "MUTANTE: "
            << m.toCSV() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  Poderes : " << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m.getNumPoderes(); i++) {
        try {
            cout << "PODER " << i + 1 << endl;
            cout << "---> Nombre: " << m.getPoder(i)->getNombre() << endl <<
                    "---> Descripcion: " << m.getPoder(i)->getDescripcion() << endl <<
                    "---> Afecta a: " << m.getPoder(i)->getAfectaA() << endl <<
                    "---> Capacidad destructiva: " << m.getPoder(i)->getCapacidadDestructiva()
                    << endl << endl;
        } catch (invalid_argument &error) {
            cerr << "ERROR: " << error.what() << endl << endl;
        }
    }
    //ToDo, Mostrar los poderes del mutante

}

/***@brief Visualiza los datos de todos los miembros de un equipo mutante*/
void visualiza(EquipoMutante& eq) {
    std::cout << "EQUIPO: " << eq.getNombre()
            << " (Base: " << eq.getBase() << ")" << std::endl
            << "============================"
            << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < eq.getNumMiembros(); i++)
        visualiza(*eq.getMutante(i));
    //ToDo, Mostrar los mutantes del equipo (usar función anterior)

}

//ToDo, Método para almacenar un vector de punteros a mutantes
//almacenaMutantesCSV()

void almacenaMutantesCSV(Mutante* v[], int tamv, std::string nombreArchivo) {
    std::fstream archivo;
    archivo.open(E:\UJA\Programacion Orientada a Objetos\Practicas\Ejercicios hechos\Practica 7\P_7_Material\nombreArchivo);
    if (archivo.good()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tamv; i++) {
            archivo << v[i]->toCSV() << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    // Crea un array de 5 punteros a mutantes, asignándoles los valores a sus
    // atributos directamente en el código fuente
    Mutante * mutantes[5];
    mutantes[0] = new Mutante("John", "MAX", 20001214, "EEUU");
    mutantes[1] = new Mutante("Carmen", "INTELL", 19971014, "Espana");
    mutantes[2] = new Mutante("Mary", "BREAKER", 19920816, "Alemania");
    mutantes[3] = new Mutante("Pablo", "CUTTER", 20010812, "Espana");
    mutantes[4] = new Mutante("Carlos", "USEFULL", 19900505, "Espana");

    // Crea dos equipos mutantes, asignando al primero los mutantes que ocupan
    // las posiciones pares del array, y al segundo los de las posiciones impares
    EquipoMutante equipo_1("EQUIPO 1", "Estadounidense");
    EquipoMutante equipo_2("EQUIPO 2", "Espanola");
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 2)
            equipo_1.addMutante(mutantes[i]);
    } catch (length_error &error) {
        cerr << "ERROR: " << error.what() << endl;
    }

    try {
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i += 2)
            equipo_2.addMutante(mutantes[i]);
    } catch (length_error &error) {
        cerr << "ERROR: " << error.what() << endl;
    }

    // Añade varios poderes a cada mutante, utilizando los métodos ya
    // implementados: usando datos o objetos de tipo Poder
    // Muestra por la consola la información de cada equipo mutante en formato CSV
    PoderFisico poder_1("Frio", "Capacidad de enfriar lo que toca", "Objetos", 600);
    PoderPsiquico poder_2("Movimiento", "Mueve cosas sin contacto fisico", "Objetos", 1600);
    mutantes[0]->addPoderFisico("Fuerza Extrema", "Mucha más fuerza de lo normal", "Todos", 1000);
    mutantes[0]->addPoder(poder_2);
    mutantes[1]->addPoderPsiquico("MuListo", "Inteligencia anormalmente alta", "Forzudos", 330);
    mutantes[2]->addPoder(poder_1);
    mutantes[3]->addPoderFisico("Velocidad", "Se mueve extremadamente rapido", "Todos", 200);
    mutantes[4]->addPoderPsiquico("Calculo", "Realiza operaciones muy complejas con la mente", "Todos", 800);

    visualiza(equipo_1);
    visualiza(equipo_2);

    //Guardamos datos de mutantes en fichero CSV
    almacenaMutantesCSV(mutantes, 5, "mutantes.csv");

    // Destruye todos los objetos creados en memoria dinámica antes de la
    // finalización del programa
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        delete mutantes[i];
        mutantes[i] = nullptr;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

El fichero de cabeceras de la clase Mutante:

```
#ifndef MUTANTE_H
#define MUTANTE_H

#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Poder.h"
#include "PoderFisico.h"
#include "PoderPsiquico.h"

using std::string;

/**
 * @brief Clase Muntante
 */
class Mutante {
public:
    static const int MAX_PODERES = 10; ///< Max. moderes de un mutante

public:
    Mutante();
    Mutante(string nombre, string apodo, int fechaN,string nacionalidad);
    Mutante(const Mutante& orig);
    virtual ~Mutante();
    void setNombreReal(string nombreReal);
    string getNombreReal() const;
    void setNacionalidad(string nacionalidad);
    string getNacionalidad() const;
    void setFechaDeNacimiento(int fechaDeNacimiento);
    int getFechaDeNacimiento() const;
    void setApodo(string apodo);
    string getApodo() const;

    string toCSV() const;

    Mutante& operator=(const Mutante& orig);
    int getNumPoderes();
    Poder* getPoder(int cual);
    void addPoder(std::string nombre, std::string descripcion, std::string afectaA, float capacidadD);
    void borraPoder(int cual);
    float capacidadDestructivaTotal();
    void addPoderFisico(std::string nombre, std::string descripcion, std::string afectaA, float capacidadD);
    void addPoderPsiquico(std::string nombre, std::string descripcion, std::string afectaA, float capacidadD);
    void addPoder(const Poder& poder);
    void addPoder(const PoderFisico& poderF);
    void addPoder(const PoderPsiquico& poderP);

private:
    string _nombreReal = "---";
    string _apodo = "---";
    int _fechaDeNacimiento = 0;
    string _nacionalidad = "---";
    int _numPoderes = 0;
    Poder* _poderes[MAX_PODERES];
};

#endif /* MUTANTE_H */
```

Y también el cuerpo de la función **toCSV** en cuestión:

```
string Mutante::toCSV() const {
    std::stringstream aux;
    aux << _nombreReal << ";"
            << _apodo << ";"
            << _fechaDeNacimiento << ";"
            << _nacionalidad;

    return aux.str();
}
```

Creo que no falta más código para poder ver y/o reproducir de dónde viene el problema, pero si es así díganmelo.

EN RESPUESTA A **PaperBirdMaster**:

Si solo pongo el nombre en la carpeta del ejecutable no se crea nada. He mirado en TODAS las carpetas del proyecto sin ver nada (en la del ejecutable concretamente solo está el .exe), también con la opción de archivos ocultos activa por si era eso.

Si pongo la ruta como cadena de texto, tal y como has indicado, el programa corre bien (*RUN SUCCESSFUL*), pero el archivo sigue sin aparecer donde yo lo pongo en la ruta (ni en ningún otro sitio). La función ha quedado ahora así (no he cambiado nada más en el código):

```
void almacenaMutantesCSV(Mutante* v[], int tamv, std::string nombreArchivo) {
    std::fstream archivo;
    archivo.open("E:/Universidad/Programacion Orientada a Objetos/Practicas/Ejercicios hechos/Practica 7/P_7_Material/" + nombreArchivo);
    if (archivo.good()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tamv; i++) {
            archivo << v[i]->toCSV() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

He hecho las mismas pruebas con la doble barra decreciente, pero también sin éxito. Con el Depurador he podido comprobar que no se entra en el **if**, osea que `archivo.good()` es **false**.

En cuanto a lo de la librería **filesystem**, me parece más complicado, y además he estado mirando un poco por *cppreference* y no sé si podrá dar problemas por ser experimental. A ser posible, preferiría hacerlo sin esa librería, e incluso sin poner ruta (solo nombre del archivo), por no liarla si cambia de SO el proyecto (cada profesor usa el que quiere, creo que el que me corrige esto macOS).

Comment: Tu edición no cambia en nada mi respuesta: Si no especificas ruta, el archivo se crea en la ruta de ejecución, revisa los parámetros de depuración de tu compilador, sea cual sea este. La cabecera `<filesystem>` ofrece herramientas estandarizadas para acceder al sistema de archivos, no es ni más ni menos complicada que otras opciones, es experimental según el compilador, otros compiladores la tienen ya integrada.

Comment: Gracias, ha quedado solucionado. `fstream` no crea el archivo automáticamente, `ofstream` sí. Me lo indicó un profesor, hice el cambio y problema solucionado. Por cierto, perdonad la torpeza, ¿cómo sé yo el compilador que tengo? Yo instalé Cygwin y unos cuantos paquetes, pero ni idea de cuál era el compilador.

Answer (score 4):

> He intentado usar solo el nombre del archivo para crearlo y usarlo [...] Pero no tengo ni idea de si ese archivo se está creando correctamente, no se está creado, o dónde está.

Cuando sólo indicas el nombre del archivo al crearlo, el archivo se crea en la carpeta de ejecución del programa. Para saber cuál es esta carpeta deberás revisar los parámetros de depuración de tu compilador, sea cual sea este.

> He decidido que es mejor crearlo en una ruta específica.

Ten en cuenta que las rutas se expresan de manera diferente según el sistema operativo, en sistemas Windows (que parece que es el sistema en que trabajas) las rutas se separan con barra descendente (`\`) que casualmente es el mismo símbolo que se usa para [escapar caracteres](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) así que una ruta como:

> E:\Universidad\Programacion Orientada a Objetos\Practicas\Ejercicios hechos\Practica 7\P_7_Material\nombreArchivo

Se traduciría a:

> E:UniversidadProgramacion Orientada a ObjetosPracticasEjercicios hechosPractica 7P_7_Material
>
> ombreArchivo

Date cuenta que el `\n` de `\nombreArchivo` se transforma en salto de línea. O eso haría si estuviera contenido en una cadena de caracteres, sin embargo has puesto la ruta en crudo:

```
void almacenaMutantesCSV(Mutante* v[], int tamv, std::string nombreArchivo) {
    std::fstream archivo;
    archivo.open(E:\UJA\Programacion Orientada a Objetos\Practicas\Ejercicios hechos\Practica 7\P_7_Material\nombreArchivo);
    //           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    if (archivo.good()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tamv; i++) {
            archivo << v[i]->toCSV() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Por eso te da los errores extraños. Puedes solucionar esto cambiando la barra descendente por una ascendente (`/`) y usando una cadena de caracteres en lugar de la ruta en crudo:

```
archivo.open("E:/UJA/Programacion Orientada a Objetos/Practicas/Ejercicios hechos/Practica 7/P_7_Material/nombreArchivo");
```

Yo prefiero esa solución antes que la de doblar las barras descendentes:

```
archivo.open("E:\\UJA\\Programacion Orientada a Objetos\\Practicas\\Ejercicios hechos\\Practica 7\\P_7_Material\\nombreArchivo");
```

O puedes usar la cabecera `<filesystem>`:

```
#include <filesystem>

void almacenaMutantesCSV(Mutante* v[], int tamv, std::string nombreArchivo) {
    using namespace std::experimental; // Según la versión del compilador esto no sería necesario
    std::cout << "Vamos a crear el archivo en " << filesystem::current_path().string() << '\n';

    if (std::fstream archivo{nombreArchivo})
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tamv; i++) {
            archivo << v[i]->toCSV() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. He editado el post original con la nueva información, por favor échale un ojo.